# Apache: How to link or mount local directory to a remote one on Internet?

Tags: mount, symbolic-link, apache-http-server, forwarding

I have `apache2` web server installed on `Ubuntu Server` which provides the service at `192.168.122.108:80`. Also, I've been created a directory named `ubuntu` on apache's root directory.

Now, the idea is to link or mount this local directory to `http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` or it's `ftp` pal! I mean if someone request `http://192.168.122.108/ubuntu` or `http://192.168.122.108/ubuntu/dists`, the local apache server should provide service from ubuntu.com transparently!

What's your idea? how this is possible without using a new port and `iptables` as forwarder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a local DNS server?

Comment: @ir01, yes we do.

Comment: We have a same problem. We clone the sites(Netbeans rep. Ubuntu rep.) and redirect the DNS records to local address. Why the @davidgo answer is NOT correct(or impractical)?

Comment: @ir01, just read my first comment on his answer; I would not like to CLONE that sites, I would like to create a symbolic link in Apache to outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a "fake" ir.archive.ubuntu.com site, and then modify the DNS for people using this site.  Depending on how this is done it could range from modifying the hosts file (easy, just add the line 192.168.122.108 ir.archive.ubuntu.com)  to redirecting DNS to your nameserver and providing the answer you want with a specially crafted zone or a modified routing table.

I note you asked how its possible without using a new port and iptables as a forwarder.  I have assumed above that this means "no IPTables".  Depending on how literally you interpret this you might be able to insert a transparent proxy in the path - this would use a transparent proxy server and iptables, but no "new port".

Comment: In your first paragraph, I need to completely clone `http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and all underlying staff recursively to my local fake server, right? if so, actualy I asked this question here to avoid this! I just try to found out if Apache supports this scenario via a simple command like `mount /ubuntu http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` while linux simply can do this on file systems!

Comment: You have not specified what you want clearly, but you can probably do it by setting up a reverse proxy in Apache using mod-proxy to get parts of the archive off the original server, and serve parts of it locally.  All traffic would still need to go through your server though and you will still need to redirect the traffic to your server in place of the real one.  From what you described the hard bit will be probably be getting the traffic to your server.